# Prevent Angular7 project from spamming/flooding errors in console

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, frontend, ngx-admin

I am building a project based on Angular7.

I have started from the `ngx-admin` empty `starter-kit` branch:

https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/tree/starter-kit

Sometimes, during the development, I make mistakes, so the console should blame me for this, but only once. But at the moment it hangs the browser for some 20 secs and then prints more than 1500 errors.

how it looks like:

I am using a property of an undefined variable.

So, I see error:

[image]

But then I see another error, appering too many times.

[image]

I haven't found any cumstom error handlers enabled for this, so I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
  protected createPositions(memberPositions?: number[]) {
    return this.fb.group(
      positions.map(position => {
        return this.fb.control(!!~memberPositions.indexOf(position.id));
      }),
      { validator: requireCheckedValidator(1) }
    );
  }

  get formPositions() {
    return this.form.get('positions') as any;
  }

  get formCheckboxes() {
    const arr = [];
    Object.keys(this.formPositions.controls).forEach(key => {
      arr.push(this.formPositions.controls[key]);
    });

    return arr;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the lines 117 and 122 of members-add.component.ts?

Comment: I have added to the question code + screenshot.

Comment: @Sergej are you declaring `public myGroup: FormGroup` in your component? Also, at line 117 of `members-add.component.ts`, is `this.form` defined?